# Autoencoder Custom Error Metric not working as intended

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have created a custom error metric to measure the success of an autoencoder implemented in Keras and sklearn. At a high level, it computes the loss for each of the output neurons separately (num_features = num_input_neurons = num_output_neurons), and returns the highest and lowest loss of the features over the whole testing dataset, as well as the names of the two features themselves.

The implementation of the custom loss functions look like this:

```
import keras.backend as K

def get_argmax_max(features, diff_list):
    return [features[K.argmax(diff_list)], K.max(diff_list).numpy()]

def get_argmin_min(features, diff_list):
    return [features[K.argmin(diff_list)], K.min(diff_list).numpy()]
```

```
# features = [list of feature names]
decoded_prediction = test_autoencoder.predict(testing_data)
individual_diff_list = list(abs(x-y) for x, y in zip(decoded_prediction, testing_data))
error_list = np.mean(individual_diff_list, axis=0)
max_err = get_argmax_max(features, error_list)
min_err = get_argmin_min(features, error_list)
```

I have added two columns to train and test - one completely random, and one uniform (eg: all 1s) - in order to test the success of this custom metric. My hypothesis is that the custom metric will identify the uniform column as having the minimum error (as it is very simple to learn) and the random column as having the maximum error (as it is not possible to learn well). In practice, however, this is not the case, and the metric often selects random other columns instead of the expected uniform and random columns. I have ensured that the range of the random column exceeds that of all columns in the dataset, tested with sufficiently large encoding dimension, and have also tried running for a large number of epochs to no avail.

Comment: did you try running a test with only these two columns (uniform and random)? Also, what is the volume of data  you are using and what is the network architecture? There can be a lot of different problems with your model or your data and we need more info to try and suggest something

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I've tried running with just the two columns and it still fails. The network architecture is very simple:

`input = Input(shape=(input_dim))`
`encoded = Dense(encoding_dim)(input)`
`decoded = Dense(input_dim, activation="linear")(encoded)`
`autoencoder = Model(input, decoded)`

I'm using mse loss. Regarding data volume, I'm using 3000x10 (rows, cols) for training and 500x10 for testing (including the two extra uniform and random cols).

Comment: And what is the mse by the end of training?

Comment: For 1 epoch, adam optimizer, encoding_dim=3, and linear activation, MSE loss reaches about 3.9 for 9 columns in the range 1-10 (with the additional uniform column of 1s). MSE validation is (surprisingly?) lower - at 3.1. For 5 epochs, MSE is 0.478 and val MSE is 0.45. After running a few more tests, it would seem that encoding dimension actually influences the metric's decision. For encoding dim = 3 it seems to work as intended, but for encoding_dim = 5 things start going wrong.

Comment: I would actually try more epochs. Encoding dim and the architecture in general will have a big impact on training, so I would advise to experiment on that, also consider adding an extra hidden layer each side of the encoder layer. Another thing you need to be conscious of is the scale of your data, if your values are in the range 1-10, then the random column you are adding should also be in that range.